# Prepress: I do not know the printer, what color profiles should I use?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-profile, prepress

IMPORTANT: I dont know who the printer is or will be -- the PDF goes to an unknown layout person who will incorporate it in the publication (book). That would make it for offset printing I believe.

Background:
I do semi-technical illustrations which are used in publications. I never hear anything once I've sent off the figures -- until I see them in print. Till now these illustrations have only been B/W.

I now want to prepare full-colour PDFs which, I emphasise, will be given to an unknown layout person and printed somewhere unknown. So,
*I'm wondering should I use no color profile -- or does it matter?*

[image: PDF dialog - color output.]
PDF dialog - color output. Preset is "Press Quality" changed to appropriate destination for "European Prepress 2" (see below).
I'm using save-as PDF in illustrator (CS4) preserving illustrator editing capabilities.

I am based in Europe, my color settings in illustrator are set to:
"Europe prepress 2"

[image: Color settings: "Europe prepress 2"]

Document color mode is CMYK.
All inks are (perecntages of) CMYK.

FWIW I'm self-taught i.e. ignorant of many things I probably should know.
TIA for any help!

Comment: You forgot to mention what the printing method is

Comment: Is it offset, flexo, or digital printing?

Comment: Also, doesn't your printer have a website? Have you looked there yet? They should have guidelines on their website.

Comment: In my post I say I dont know who the printer is: the PDF file will go to an *unknown* layout person who incorporates it in a publication (book). Wouldn't that be offset printing?

Comment: @LateralTerminal I added an edit ('Important') to the start of my post above, which will hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: I generally avoid profiles, as I understand that there's no reason to use profiles except for converting among different color models. If you are designing for print in CMYK, I'd think you want your colors to remain as they are. You do need more information though about how they are going to place your artwork in the publication. When will it get rasterized? Will it go through a mode conversion? What stock and screen settings are used for printing? This I would need to know to spec colors (so I could consider dot gain, paper whiteness, and required raster resolution).

Comment: hi user8356, it's reassuring to hear what you say about profiles. Because I dont know the layout person (they have not yet been chosen for this job), I have no idea re these other questions. I guess I will have to trust the layout person (or the printer) to look after them -- presumably they will set these settings for the whole publication. FWIW the quality of the print is normally quite high in these publications.

Comment: When you choose your printer they are going to tell you how they do things. I think you're worrying about things prematurely. When you finally choose a printer then you will have to figure out how to setup your artwork based off what they tell you. And everything @t_o_m said.

Comment: If you're in doubt keep as much as you can editable so that you can fix it later if you find out their specifications are different.

Comment: @LateralTerminal, good point about keeping things editable. I think you're getting confused though: I am t_o_m, and I am (also) the person who asked the question. I think you didnt read my edit (top of OP). To emphasise: I will have no contact with the printer -- the files will be completely gone from my care! Hence the question.

Comment: I meant @user8356 sorry, I cant edit that comment anymore

Comment: The people receiving your work will appreciate if it is still editable because they can fix anything that isn't within their specifications. If it's really bad they will send it back to you.

Comment: If the layouter will be using something like Illustrator or InDesign to make the final layout, **they** will make sure your embedded artwork is properly converted to the correct colour profile; or if they have it printed by a good printer, they may send off all the artwork to be embedded off to the printer and have them process it specifically for their printing equipment. It’s not your responsibility to profile artwork that someone else will be sending off to the printer—you can’t, in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In this answer I assume you are creating vector graphics and text without images.*

In your case, with *Color Conversion* set to *Convert to Destination (Preserve Numbers)*, the color profile doesn't affect the CMYK *numbers* you have chosen, so it doesn't matter which profile you choose. You are not using color management, you are kind of "programming" which raster percentages to print "manually".

This is traditionally the way graphic designers have worked for many years and it is a very common way to work (I do it most of the time myself), but it is not really color managed. When choosing the percentages of a color manually it is like choosing a color marker and then use that same marker on any kind of paper. I like that approach because of its simplicity, but the color will look different on different medias.

A way to make use of color management would be to make everything in RGB and then convert to the correct CMYK profile on export. If you have a calibrated ISO certificated screen and use *Proof Colors* with the correct profile, the colors you see on your screen should (more or less) match a print made by an ISO certificated print house.

But there are downsides to working in all RGB and reasons to work in CMYK instead. The conversion to the correct color profile ensures the best preservation of the colors, but in offset there are other things to look after. For example, thin lines and small text can look blurry if printed with more than one ink, 100% of a color creates a sharp contour, everything below get a (subtle) raggedness from the raster dots. Neutral greys made from all four inks will often get an unwanted color tint. Furthermore, it seems more intuitive for many designers to work with CMYK colors for graphics.

**For you, I would recommend the following:**

- Work in CMYK if that's what you are most comfortable with. Keep your current settings.
- In "Edit/Preferences", make sure "Appearance of Black" is set to both display and output all blacks accurately.
- In "View/Proof Setup/Customize..." setup like below. Now, once in while turn on "View/Proof Colors" to preview how your colors would look if printed on coated paper ("Coated FOGRA27" is a good standard "guess"). You could try changing the "Device to Simulate" to "Uncoated FOGRA29" to see if your colors looks ok on uncoated paper.

[image: Proof Setup]

- Since you don't know which kind of paper your illustration is printed on, avoid using colors with too much *total ink* (C+M+Y+K). For coated paper the limit is approximately 300-320% and for uncoated paper it is approximately 250-280%.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you @Wolff. My illustrations do have lots of fine lines and small text, but I have been careful to only use 100K or single inks (e.g. 100%C for rivers on maps). I will have a look tomorrow at the view proof colours.

Comment: Proof Setup / Proof colors is a good tip: 
I'm surprised how much it changes everything -- makes everything a lot cooler (when set to "Coated FOGRA27" which does seem to be a good guess seeing as it will be printed on coated paper).

Comment: Glad I could help. Another nice tool for working with colors: "Window/Separations Preview". Here you can switch the inks on and off to check your own work. Makes it easier to spot problems with different blacks for example.

Comment: "Window/Separations Preview" is a very nice way of checking. Illustrator is odd (imo) in not showing what colours are *actually* in use: another trick is to select all, then click 'New color group' in the Swatch panel -- that way I can see what colours are in use.

Comment: Re the 'Proof setup' it doesnt remember the setting 'Simulate paper colour' -- neither in general nor for a particular file (ai CS4) which is a bit of a pain. (I'm working my way through about 50 files.) I gave it a custom shortcut.
Re the colours shown -- they do look a lot closer to prints I've been making here on high quality glossy paper. The white though is completely off -- it's got a definite blue, almost lilac tint. I presume this is my monitor: it's not professional grade, but, FWIW is supposed to have very good RGB coverage & calibration out of the box. This CMYK though...